# How to detect indicators and there state (ON-OFF, color, blinking) in meter at real time within 50-100 ms using emgucv/opencv/Aforge.Net/Accord.Net

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

**Meter image to detect indicators**
[![Meter image to detect indicators][1]][1]

I want to track current status of every indicator on meter in real time. Two indicators can be shown on same place at different instance of time

For implementing speedometer indicator detection I tried following approaches,

1. Background subtraction method - 
   In this method we had stored an base image of meter in off condition before testing. Then we captured every frame after starting test and subtracted this frame from the base image. Then we checked for area of interest (Indicator position) in the subtracted image, if a blob of the size of indicator was detected we considered indicator to be ON else if no blob or small size blob was detected we considered indicator as OFF.

ISSUE faced in above implementation was that when any other graphics got displayed in this area OR if meter plays any animations and that animation passes through indicator area, then a wrong blob was detected and wrong result was obtained.

2. Open CV Template matching method - 
   When meter is configured for first time the indicator are added by user by drawing rectangle on image. During this a template image of indicator is stored. During test execution this template image is searched in area of interest (Indicator position).If image matches to template image we considered indicator to be ON else we considered indicator as OFF.

ISSUE faced in above implementation was that few indicators were displayed differently in ignition on state and ignition off state then template image match failed due to different background

For example below indicator can be shown in two ways on meter depending on ignition states(ignition OFF and ignition ON respectively)

**Image for front fog indicator ON in ignition ON state**
[![Image for front fog indicator ON in ignition ON state ][2]][2]

**Image for front fog indicator ON in ignition OFF state**
[![Image for front fog indicator ON in ignition OFF state][3]][3]

3. Open CV Edge detection + Template matching method –
   To remove the background issue in above method I tried to convert icon into outline using canny edge detection and then trying to match the templates but the results are still inconsistent.

Comment: In this application, template matching should be good for finding indicators. This is true if the position of the camera taking the image doesn't change and your target regions are always the same size  and do not rotate. I would try different [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) schemes and [equalization](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html)

Comment: @andrew Using template matching above mentioned scenario of front fog indicator with two different representations is not consistent? Can you suggest any work around?

Comment: @PratikThorat I wanted to try an experiment with HOG (Histogram of Oriented Gradients) matching.  Although it is still template matching it is a bit more robust because it uses the gradient(lines). This will remove solid colored backgrounds but leave lines/edges which should work on your last two images. I didn't have time to test this myself (which is why I didn't leave the comment) but it could work. Good luck https://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/

Comment: @andrew Thank you very much for your time and guidance. I will surely try this method and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Nice to display us your thought process!

### Problem:

For such shape detection and variations, you biggest problem is generalization. The shape of the indication is consistent (object), but the scenario changes (background). Such "heuristically" approach won't return good results given that amount of variation.

### Solutions:

Your should implement a machine learning approach to the problem, elaborate your own dataset of indicators and labels, organize everything and train your own solution.

1. **SVM - Support Vector Machine**: Not the most generalist approach, but generates lighter models and somewhat quick to train ones. You can even train your own SVM using Opencv. [Application example](https://github.com/ZhouJiaHuan/traffic-sign-detection) | [Training example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d73/tutorial_introduction_to_svm.html)
2. **CNN - Convolutional Neural Network**: Very generalist and somewhat noise robust, this one would definitely be my "go to" approach. The easiest and fastest way to train a object detection model is by using Keras. [Application example](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet) | [Training example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-object-detection-with-yolov3-in-keras/)

PS: Most of the techniques I brought aren't implemented in C# (mostly Python and C++), as the question demands, but once the inference models (SVM, CNN, etc.) are trained and generated, newer versions of EmguCV can import and use them seamlessly.

Comment: Thank you @Guilgerme Vogt for your reply. I would like to clear few point. Since one indicator will be having one picture(i.e. 1 INDICATOR == 1 TRAINING SAMPLE), will it work?

Comment: Also if query indicator is not trained it maps it to wrong indicator so is it possible to get confidence in keras CNN?